# What is the deal with mandb and stray cats?

Tags: man

The man page for `mandb` refers to stray cats:

> ```
> -s, --no-straycats
>        Do not spend time looking  for  or  adding  information  to  the
>        databases regarding stray cats.
> ```

There is no explanation of what a stray cat is. What's up?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the Glossary in `/usr/share/doc/man-db/man-db-manual.txt` (source is [manual/glossary.me](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/tree/manual/glossary.me)):

> cat page
>      A formatted manual page suitable for viewing on a vt100-type terminal.
>
> stray cat page
>      A cat page that does not have a relative manual page on the system,  i.e.
>      only  the  cat page was supplied or the manual page was removed after the
>      cat page had been created.

Comment: That explains the catman command too

Comment: I don't understand. A "cat page" is a manual page (as per your answer). Then (also per your answer) a "stray cat page" is "a cat page that does not have a relative manual page". The answer affirms that a "cat page" is a manual page (with some specific characteristic). What is the meaning of a cat page (that is a manual page) not having a relative manual page?

Comment: You missed the word "formatted".

Comment: Probably "related" (corresponding, matching) would be a better word than "relative."

Answer (score 6):

A [cat page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/catman/) is a particular type of man page. It is faster to display than a normal man page, but requires more hard drive space. They are created by using the `catman` command. This reads the 'regular' man pages and produces new pages with a different internal structure, called cat pages. If you create cat page(s) and then remove the original man page(s), you'll have "stray" cat page(s).

Comment: For the sake of completion, `cat` pages are usually written in 'pure' ASCII and reside on a directory structure similar/mirroring the one of `man`, also with the extension corresponding to the section (e.g. `ffmpeg.1`).