# How to display cat (not man) pages?

Tags: cat, man

In addition to **man** pages, some UNIX documentation is also available as **cat** pages. (Cf. this question: [What is the deal with mandb and stray cats?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185359/what-is-the-deal-with-mandb-and-stray-cats))

From `man catman`:

```
NAME
       catman - create or update the pre-formatted manual pages

SYNOPSIS
       catman [-d?V] [-M path] [-C file] [section] ...

DESCRIPTION
       catman  is used to create an up to date set of pre-formatted manual pages known as cat pages.  Cat pages are generally much faster to display than the
       original manual pages, but require extra storage space.  The decision to support cat pages is that of the local administrator, who must provide  suit‐
       able directories to contain them.

       The  options  available  to  catman are the manual page hierarchies and sections to pre-format.  The default hierarchies are those specified as system
       hierarchies in the man-db configuration file, and the default sections are either the colon-delimited contents of the environment variable $MANSECT or
       the  standard set compiled into man if $MANSECT is undefined.  Supplying catman with a set of whitespace-delimited section names will override both of
       the above.
```

My question is: what are the commands available to display cat pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a command available to display cat pages: `man`!

From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html#DEFAULTS):

> Once  a  manual  page has been located, a check is performed to find out if a relative preformatted ‘cat’ file
> already exists and is newer than the nroff file.  If it does and  is,  this  preformatted  file  is  (usually)
> decompressed  and then displayed, via use of a pager.  The pager can be specified in a number of ways, or else
> will fall back to a default is used (see option `-P` for details).  If no cat is found  or  is  older  than  the
> nroff file, the nroff is filtered through various programs and is shown immediately.

> If a cat file can be produced (a relative cat directory exists and has appropriate permissions), `man` will compress and store the cat file in the background.

To view a raw `cat` file, use a tool such as `less -R` or `more` — `cat` files are simply pre-rendered man pages. (You’ll need this for stray cats.)

Comment: "(You’ll need this for stray cats.)" -- I like cats -- everbody should help stray cats